# localectl list-x11-keymap-variants gb, no qwerty variant

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, bluetooth

I have this weird problem where my Bluetooth Logitech MX keyboard automatically goes onto the `US` layout even though in my `.xinitrc` I have:

```
setxkbmap -layout gb &
```

I did some Googling, and [I am told](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Using_localectl) I should run the following:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap layout [model [variant [options]]]
```

I didn't know what was meant by `[model [variant [options]]]`, so I tried something and got:

```
~ ❯ localectl set-x11-keymap layout gb
Failed to set keymap: Specified keymap cannot be compiled, refusing as invalid.
~ ❯
```

After some more reading, it turns out I do need the variant, but I didn't know what my options were, so I ran:

```
~ ❯ localectl list-x11-keymap-variants gb
colemak
colemak_dh
dvorak
dvorakukp
extd
intl
mac
mac_intl
pl
```

I recognise `dvorak` and `colemak` as keyboard layouts that are different to `qwerty` which is what I want, but I am confused that `qwerty` isn't even listed! Had it been listed, I would have then ran:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap layout gb qwerty
```

I of course don't know if that would've worked either, but I'm basically trying things to get my Bluetooth keyboard to be the standard qwerty UK English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if setting the keyboard layout this way solves your initial problem with your Bluetooth keyboard, but I can tell you why the command doesn't work and what the variants are meant for.

You tried:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap layout gb
```

The error message is scarce in details, sadly. But the `layout` is the placeholder that should be replaced with the desired layout, e.g. `gb` in your case:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap gb
```

Regarding the non-presence of a QWERTY variant, this is because QWERTY is the default for `gb`, so you don't need to specify it. The variants are only for things deviating from the default.

Apart form the excellent ArchWiki, I can recommend looking into man pages for details about a command or configuration, the one for [localectl](https://man.archlinux.org/man/localectl.1) is not overly helpful in my opinion, but often they are well written with usage examples towards the end. If you have the `man-pages` package installed, you can open them in a terminal with e.g. `man localectl`.

Comment: Thank you! you were right about the format of the command. `localectl set-x11-keymap gb` ran successfully, sadly my Bluetooth keyboard is still US English.

Answer (score 1):

I have created my own keyboard layout: a mix of US and DK called "usdk" and as this has no variant, I was initially not able to set select this via localectl.

But it turned out after a bit of experimentation that an empty quoted string actually works, so this is how I do it now:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap usdk pc105 "" caps:escape
```